# Why does if expression ignore condition in F#?

Tags: f#

I'm trying check an array if it is arranged. The problem is that in the method Verificar Fsharp ignore the if and 'ordenado' take always the value 0.

```
open System

type VerificarOrden() = 
  let valor = Array.empty
  let (valor : int array) = Array.create 10 1
  let ordenado = 0

  member this.Inicializar() = 
    for f in 0 .. valor.Length - 1 do
      printfn "Introduzaca el valor %d: " f
      let res=System.Console.ReadLine()
      Array.set valor f (System.Int32.Parse(res))

    member this.Verificar() = 
      for f in 1 .. valor.Length - 1 do
        if valor.[f] > valor.[f-1]
        then ordenado = 0
        else ordenado = 1
        printfn "f: %d\nanterior: %d\nordenado: %d\n" valor.[f] valor.[f-1] ordenado

    member this.Imprimir() =
      if ordenado = 0 
      then printfn "La matriz esta ordenada"
      else printfn "La matriz no esta ordenada"

let chekear = VerificarOrden()
chekear.Inicializar()
chekear.Verificar()
chekear.Imprimir()
```

Because of this, it always shows that the array is arranged although it isn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in F# are by default immutable: they never change and can't be updated. So the code

```
Type VerificarOrden()
    let ordenado = 0
    ...
```

means essentially that `ordenado` is a constant with value 0. In your conditional

```
    if valor.[f] > valor.[f-1]
    then ordenado = 0
    else ordenado = 1
```

the equal-sign does not update the constant `ordenado`–that would be meaningless–but rather, it *tests* whether the value of `ordenado` is 0, returning a boolean. The above code has the same semantics as

```
    if valor.[f] > valor.[f-1]
    then true
    else false
```

The compiler/interpreter likely tried to tell you as much with the warning

> warning FS0020: This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'bool'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, or 'let' to bind the result to a name.

You want `ordenado` to be mutable. This is what you want, then:

```
type VerificarOrden() = 
    ...
    let mutable ordenado = 0

    ...
    if valor.[f] > valor.[f-1]
    then ordenado <- 0
    else ordenado <- 1
    ...
```

The `mutable` keyword means that the value of `ordenado` can be changed. The assignment `ordenado <- 0` then changes the value.

By the way, once you've made `ordenado` mutable, your program still has a bug in that it thinks the sequence 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-8-7-9 is ordered. I'll leave that as an exercise ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is

```
 ordenado = 1
```

this is not an assignment but a comparison. 
In F# = operator has two meanings, binding (not assignment) to let statements or comparison

You can't assign to a let bound field, they are immutable. To assign it you should make it mutable and use <- operator